# Why does my program only read the last line from a file? (C++)

Tags: c++

So I am required to make this file reading program that outputs information in the form of test marks in a table, then finds their average, and finally finds both highest and lowest value for a test. This program is required to make use of structures and arrays. I have tried building it with a function to read marks from the file. However for some reason, while the names were read and displayed perfectly, the program would only read test marks from **the final line** in the file. I initially suspected that there is a problem in the looping, however to my limited knowledge I coded it correctly, and I tried messing with the structure arrays next, to no avail. Where did I went wrong?

```
//variables
const int ROWS = 6;
const int COLS = 3;
    
//structure
struct marks
    {
    string name;
    float test, total;
    float average, MAX, MIN;
    };
//functions
void input(marks []);

void input(marks s[])
{
    int i,j;
    fin.open("EE209_marks.txt");
    for (i=0; i<ROWS;i++)
    {
        fin>> s[i].name;
        for (j=0; j<COLS; j++)
        {
            fin>> s[i].test;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
int i,j;
 marks studs[6];
    input (studs);

cout<< left;
for (i=0; i<ROWS;i++)
    {
        cout<<setw(18)<< studs[i].name;
    for (j=0; j<COLS; j++)
    {cout <<setw(8)<< studs[j].test;}
    cout<<endl;
    }
```

Comment: `fin>> s[i].test;` This looks like you are trying to read `3` values in the same variable on top of each other. In a `for (j=0; j<COLS; j++)` loop you would expect *something* to depend on `j`.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you only have room for one test per student (`float test`), but it seems that you really have 3 tests per student. Therefore, you should do something like replace `float test` with `float tests[COLS]`, and then in your `input` function, populate it with `fin >> s[i].tests[j]`.

Also, you're printing it out incorrectly - you use the variable `j` in your `main` function to represent the column number `(j=0; j<COLS)`, but then you access `studs[j]`. After you fix your `input` function, you should see your printing logic should be almost identical to it.

Comment: I changed the `test` to `test [ROWS][COLS]` and got the test output right, but now the "total" acts up and only displays the test value, even though it was supposed to add up test scores in a row: `for (j=0; j<COLS; j++) { s[i].total[i] = 0; fin>> s[i].test[i][j]; s[i].total[i] = s[i].total[i] + s[i].test[i][j]; }`. My guess it has something to do with the arrays, i'm stuck on which one though.

Comment: Why `test[ROWS][COLS]`, and not just `test[COLS]`? You already handled the `ROWS` with the fact that you have `ROWS` number of `marks` objects